# Java SocketServer to run on Azure Web App

Tags: websocket, azure-web-app-service, serversocket

I am writing a socket server with java SocketServer.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    threads = new ArrayList<>();
    index = 0;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT); //PORT variable is currently equal to 5000
        System.out.println(serverSocket);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
```

It is working perfectly on my local server, i successfully connected to the server with my clients, everything works as my wish.
I am triying to run my socket server on a Web host(Azure Web App). I created a web app on Java with spring, it is working perfectly on my local server. My web server working on port 8080 and my socket working on 5000. But when i do this on Azure Web App service(creating a web host for free basically), my socket server not working because port 5000 is closed in Azure host, and it won't let you open it. When i try to work my socket server on 80 port(same as the site's open port), its throwing an error becuase socket server can't using an used port. So my question is, how can i run my socket server on a Azure Web App, or any web hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question! Could you please confirm if you running on Linux Free sku ?

As "Web Sockets are not currently supported for Linux apps on Free App Service Plans. We are working on removing this limitation and plan to support up to 5 web socket connections on Free App Service plans."

You may refer to this doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-app-service-linux#web-sockets

Incase you are on running on Windows please confirm if you have enabled the Web sockets on from configuration tab.You need to enable the Web sockets options in the tab Application settings on Azure portal or configure the web.config file for adding the content  if you want to use
the websocket feature.

[image]

Also, Azure webapps only listen on the ports 80 & 443, please see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening

And for the limits of websockets per app service instance for different tier, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#app-service-limits.

Let us know if further query.